# How to save the value of the last element on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### What I have

I have a form for ordering parts where you can display info about a part through ajax when you type the article code. This data gets displayed in a table, next you can choose between available suppliers in the table and click on the one you want to choose.

After this you can choose to add more parts which repeats this proces.

#### What I want

Because the input fields are added dynamically when you choose to add more parts, I need to know which input is being used. Under normal circumstances you would always use the last input, but it can happen that you want to change a pre-entered article code, so if that is the case I want to give the user the option to change the supplier to that corresponding input instead of the last.

#### What I tried

I came up with the idea to select the input with a focus event, the problem with this is that when the input is focussed and than I am going to the table and click on another supplier the input loses focus and therefor doesn't know where to place the value.

**HTML** (only the relevant code)

```
Article code    <input name='article_code[]' type='text' class='article_code'>
Description     <input type='text' class='article_description' name='article_description[]' value='No articlecode specified' READONLY>
Supplier    <input type='text' class='supplier_output' name='supplier_outputt[]' value='No supplier specified'  READONLY>


<table id='supplier_table' class='sortable' width='100%'>
    <THEAD>
        <tr valign='top'>
        <th width='25%'>Supplier</th>
        <th width='25%'>Mainsupplier</th>
        <th width='25%'>Price</th>
        <th width='25%'>Article code</th>
        </tr>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY >

    </TBODY>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#supplier_table').on('click', 'tbody tr',  function(){
    var tableData = $(this).children('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    var selectedSupplier = $.trim(tableData[0]);
    var supplier_val;

    if($('.article_code').is(':focus')){
        supplier_val = $(this).closest('tr').next().next().find('.supplier_output');
        $(supplier_val).val(selectedSupplier);

    } else {
        $('.supplier_output').last().val(selectedSupplier);
    }
});
```

So basically I need to store the value of the last element on focus.

Comment: Can you not use a focus listener to listen for a focus and then within the listener just save the value to a variable?

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: @Vistari I'm not familiar with that, but I will look it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But maybe I can help you think in another direction. Use the blur event. Then store the last blurred article code in the last_val variable:

```
$('.article_code').on('blur', function(){ last_val = this.value; })
```

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: Nvm, I got it to work with your method just needed to change it a bit, thank  you!